# Unexpected result when getting DataTable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Given a `tableId` I need to access the dataTable instance and then call rows().nodes().

If I use `Datatable()` with big "D" I get the DataTable API Instance and can call rows(). But I didn't expect `fnIsDataTable()` to return false. I guess that function ask if it's the dataTable is a jQuery object. Is that true? Is there any function like this then? `fnIsDataTableApiInstance...()`?

Row clicked:

```
var dataTableBigD = $('#' + tableId).DataTable(); // big "D"
console.log('$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableBigD): ' + $.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableBigD)); // false
console.log('nodesBigD: ' + dataTableBigD.rows('.selected').nodes().length);

var dataTableLowD = $('#' + tableId).dataTable(); // low "d"
console.log('$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableLowD): ' + $.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableLowD)); // true
console.log('nodesLowD: ' + dataTableLowD.rows('.selected').nodes().length); // TypeError: t.rows is not a function
```

Output:

```
$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableBigD): false
nodesBigD: 1
$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableLowD): true
// TypeError: t.rows is not a function

$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableBigD): false
nodesBigD: 2
$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(dataTableLowD): true
// TypeError: t.rows is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `fnIsDataTable()`, the updated version for 1.10 of which is called `isDataTable()`, the following function is called:

```
DataTable.isDataTable = DataTable.fnIsDataTable = function ( table )
{
    var t = $(table).get(0);

    var is = false;

    $.each( DataTable.settings, function (i, o) {
        if ( o.nTable === t || o.nScrollHead === t || o.nScrollFoot === t ) {
            is = true;
        }
    } );

    return is;
};
```

You can see this function on line 8823 of `jquery.dataTables.js`.

The reason this function works when you initialize with `dataTable()` is because the old API created an object that looked a little like the following:

[image]

With this structure, `$(table).get(0)` would give you access to the whole `<table>` DOM object which the function would check against to see if it is a `dataTable` or not.

The new API however returns something entirely different, for example:

[image]

With this structure, `$(table).get(0)` returns `undefined` and you get false.

It appears that `DataTables` API update did not include the updating of this function. Until this is fixed the work around, if you want to keep using the new API, is to use the `table().node()` function:

```
$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable(yourTableVariableName.table().node());
```

Where `yourTableVariableName` is `dataTableBigD` or whatever else you choose.

The above will throw an error if it is not a `DataTable`. If you don't want it to throw an error and simply want `true` or `false` then pass the `id` of your table:

```
$.fn.dataTable.fnIsDataTable("#example");
```